# Pybluez client to Android Bluetooth socket server

Tags: android, python, sockets, bluetooth

I've been trying to make a two way bluetooth RFCOMM communications between an android phone (as the server) and a surface pro tablet running python pybluez(as the client). My main problem stems from the Python. It's not connecting to my android phone that is waiting. I manually connected the two devices and then started the server (Android phone). It gets stuck on "TrackingFlow. Listening...". When I run the Python script I get the error below. I found some other stack overflow issues but they weren't explicit.

**Java Client Side:**

```
private static String btAdress = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("08C2B2EF-7C87-3D00-0CDC-9A2ADC420BFF");
public BluetoothDevice device;


private static final int DISCOVERABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 0x1;
private boolean CONTINUE_READ_WRITE = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    log.debug(Logs.DEV_DEBUG, "[rosie] Running the rosie program");
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    enableBackButton();
    addViewOnUiThread("Rosie Project ");
    setContentView(R.layout.rosie_project_activity);
    //Always make sure that Bluetooth server is discoverable during listening...
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, DISCOVERABLE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    addViewOnUiThread("TrackingFlow Creating thread to start listening...");
    new Thread(reader).start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(socket != null){
        try{
            is.close();
            os.close();
            socket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        CONTINUE_READ_WRITE = false;
    }
}

private BluetoothSocket socket;
private InputStream is;
private OutputStreamWriter os;
private Runnable reader = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        try {
            BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("RosieProject", MY_UUID);
            addViewOnUiThread("TrackingFlow. Listening...");
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            addViewOnUiThread("TrackingFlow. Socket accepted...");
            is = socket.getInputStream();
            os = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            new Thread(writter).start();

            int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            //Keep reading the messages while connection is open...
            while(CONTINUE_READ_WRITE){
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
                if (bytesRead != -1) {
                    String result = "";
                    while ((bytesRead == bufferSize) && (buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)){
                        result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
                        bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
                    }
                    result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
                    sb.append(result);
                }
                addViewOnUiThread("TrackingFlow. Read: " + sb.toString());
                //Show message on UIThread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(RosieProjectActivity.this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
};

private Runnable writter = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int index = 0;
        while(CONTINUE_READ_WRITE){
            try {
                os.write("Message From Server" + (index++) + "\n");
                os.flush();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}


protected void enableBackButton() {
    new AwaitLatchTask() {
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void handleButtonPress(View view) {
    //Clear the result set
    addViewOnUiThread("Begin Sequence");


}
```

**Python Client Side**

```
import bluetooth

bd_addr = "f8:a9:d0:1c:f9:8f"
port = 1

sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((bd_addr, port))

sock.send("hello!! 21321")

sock.close()




IOError: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: FYI I figured it out. Let me know if anybody else finds this and needs help!

Comment: please answer your own question, I'm very interested in your findings

Answer (score 0):

I think the error was due to the UUID used at server side. Whenever, server is created with a particular UUID, the client should connect to that particular UUID only. Otherwise timeout will occur.

In this case, client is trying to connect to the default UUID of serial port 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB.

To make above code work, use the default serial port UUID in server code.